# Playwright - Element not Clickable

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to click on an icon that appears on the page however despite trying everything I can think of I keep getting the following error:

```
waiting for selector "[aria-label="Comment"]"
  selector resolved to 2 elements. Proceeding with the first one.
  selector resolved to hidden <svg role="img" width="24" height="24" fill="#8e8e8e"…>…</svg>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  element is not visible
retrying click action, attempt #1
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
  element is visible, enabled and stable
  scrolling into view if needed
  done scrolling
  element is not visible
retrying click action, attempt #2
  waiting 20ms
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
```

etc etc etc.

So it looks like the element is hidden although I can't see any sign of that in the html....attached.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKuAJ.png)

Comment: Maybe you have two elements with the "Comment" label?

Comment: Yeah I do but you can see that it's selecting the first one, which is the correct one.

Comment: Update: it's actually the second one I need to select, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Improve the selector so you pick the second element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth` locator's method to get second element:

```js
page.locator('svg[aria-label="Comment"]').nth(1);
```

or shorter version:

```js
page.locator('svg[aria-label="Comment"] >> nth=1');
```

Keep in mind that's zero-based numbering.

Comment: Hi, thanks very @Yevhen that seemed to work, in that it found the element, how do I click on it afterwards though as locator doesn't have a click method?

Comment: That's awesome. Actually, the locator provides `click` method. I've added click action in the code block. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

shorter version

```
page.locator('svg[aria-label="Comment"] >> nth=1').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use [nth](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#get-by-nth-item) method with caution.

- 

> **WHY**? Often times, the page might change, and the locator will point to a completely different element from the one you expected. Instead, try
> to come up with a unique locator that will pass the [strictness
> criteria](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#strictness).

- 

#### Instead use [Chained Filters](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#chaining-filters)

When you have elements with various similarities, you can use the `locator.filter()` method to select the right one. You can also chain multiple filters to narrow down the selection.

For example to take a screenshot of the row with "Mary" and "Say goodbye":

```
const rowLocator = page.getByRole('listitem');

await rowLocator
    .filter({ hasText: 'Mary' })
    .filter({ has: page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Say goodbye' }) })
    .screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });
```